# Contador que a cada 20 imagens ele imprima um bloco

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma página onde terá um slide, e cada slide desse terá 20 fotos, eu encontrei um código na internet, onde basta você especificar a pasta onde ta as imagens e ele gera todo o código. O problema que estou enfrentando é que para funcionar corretamente, a cada 25 imagens ele tem que envolver essas imagens com uma class. Ex: vou exemplificar aqui com o exemplo de apenas 3 fotos, vai ficar assim

```
<div class="item">
imagem
imagem
imagem
</div>

<div class="item">
imagem
imagem
imagem
</div>
```

Aqui abaixo vou postar o código que estou usando

```
        <?php
    // variável que define o diretório das imagens
    $dir = "imagens/galeria/";
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        // verificando se o arquivo é .jpg
        if (substr($filename, -4) == ".jpg") {
            ?>
        <li><a  data-fancybox="galeria" href="<?php echo $dir; ?><?php echo $filename; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $dir; ?><?php echo $filename; ?>)"></a></li>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Não ficou claro, a divisão só será feita se tiver a partir de 25 imagens? se tiver 6 imagens, não deve ser feito?

Comment: 25, 20 ou 3 ou outro valor?

Comment: a divisão é a cada 25 imagens, eu fiz com três só para exemplificar, mas pelo o jeito eu confundi mais rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $contador = 0;
    $abreTag = TRUE;

    // variável que define o diretório das imagens
    $dir = "imagens/galeria/";
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) {
        // verificando se o arquivo é .jpg
        if (substr($filename, -4) == ".jpg") {    
            if ($contador % 25 == 0 && $abreTag) {
                $abreTag = FALSE;
                $contador = 1;
        ?>
            <div class="bendita-classe">
        <?php
            } ?>
    <li><a  data-fancybox="galeria" href="<?php echo $dir; ?><?php echo $filename; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $dir; ?><?php echo $filename; ?>)"></a></li>
        <?php
            if ($contador % 25 == 0 && !$abreTag) {
                $abreTag = TRUE;
                $contador = -1;
        ?>
            </div>
        <?php 
            }
        $contador += 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Deu certinho cara, teria como tu fazer uma explicação desse código pra eu entender melhor? sim faz uma correção aí, falta fazer o fechamento da tag php antes da li

Comment: Blz, vlw! Corrigi o código. A variável `$contador` conta as linhas. Quando ela for 0 ou 25, ele entra em ambos os ifs e verifica `$abreTag`. Se esta for verdadeira, ela abre a tag, como o nome diz, e se for falsa, fecha a tag.

Comment: Massa, Marcelo, é possível ordenar por nome? depois que coloquei no servidor online, as fotos ficaram todas fora de ordem, veja http://ggetic.hostdime.com.br/